# Lex program input doesn't terminate

Tags: c, flex-lexer

I'm not able to terminate input for a **lex program** even after pressing **ctrl D** it just keeps going on! 
What might be wrong? I am using **flex** compiler for Windows.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The question shouldn't be this downvoted i guess :)... It's a common beginner problem with lex, and some guides proceed the Linux way for EOF, so he/she should have read some guides to be counted as an effort... eitherway it's beginner i mean

Answer (score 2):

On Windows:
You need <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, which is available in Unix and Linux (on Linux just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will work)

> Note: Both work on empty lines, so after entering any text, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to go to next line (which will be empty), then these key combos will be effective.

Comment: Nope even that's not working!it shows ^Z and after I press enter it goes to next line!

Comment: @user9338604 ensure you do it on an empty line

Comment: In Windows 11, having installed WSL 2.0 (Ubuntu) Ctrl + D works fine.